# optimal way of finding differencies betwen two sets

Tags: algorithm, set, compare

I have two sets of elements and I want an optimal algorithm to find their differences or in math form: A U B - A ∩ B

One way I thought is

```
Bfound=0;
for (1->Na,i)
{
 flag=0;
 for (1->Nb,j)
 {
  if(A[i]==B[j])
  {
   flag=1;
   Bfound[j]=1;
  }

 }
 if (flag==0)
 print A[i]
}

for(1->Nb,i)
{
  if(Bfound[i]==0)
  print B[i]
}
```

Is this optimal?

Comment: if there are number, the best way is to sort the arrays (universes) with what would be like a Quick sort and then compare each element of one array with the ones of the other using the dichotomy method

Comment: No AUB is union meaning elements that belong to set A or B or both, well I asked for the symmetric difference or: A∪B-A∩B, so should I accept this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question - no, this is not optimal. The complexity of your solution is O(nm) time, where n and m are the sizes of A and B, respectively. You can improve this time to O(nlogn + mlogm), if n ~ m.

1. Sort both arrays, in `n log n + m log m` time.
2. Find the intersection in `n+m` time:

   ```
   i = 0; 
   j = 0;
   while(i < n && j < m) {
     if (A[i] == B[j]) {
       print(A[i]);
       i++;
       j++;
     } else if (A[i] < B[j]) {
       i++;
     } else {
       j++;
     } 
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! what I want is the symmetric difference A∪B-A∩B so I will print on the other two cases of the if close

Answer (score 1):

Symmetric difference: `A∪B - A∩B` i.e., return a new set with elements in either A or B but not both. The straightforward way from the definition:

```
# result = A ^ B
result = set() # start with empty set

# add all items that are in A but not in B
for item in A: # for each item in A; O(|A|), where |A| - number of elements in A
    if item not in B: # amortized O(1) (for hash-based implementation)
       result.add(item) # amortized O(1) (for hash-based implementation)

# add all items that are in B but not in A
for item in B:
    if item not in A:
       result.add(item)
```

Complexity `O(|A|+|B|)`.

In C++ the type is `unordered_set`, in Java, C# -- `HashSet`, in Python -- `set`.

Another approach ([used in Python](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Objects/setobject.c#l1648)) is to copy A into result and then try to remove B items from the result:

```
# result = A ^ B
result = set(A) # copy A into result
for item in B:
    try: result.remove(item) # O(1)
    except KeyError: # item was not in the result
        result.add(item) # add previously not-found item
```

Complexity `O(|A|+|B|)`.

Comment: I like the approach used in python
I don't understand |A|+|B|, I think the complexity will still be O(mn) unless you consider the sets ordered

Comment: @George Panic: `|x|` - number of elements in the set `x`. `+` is arithmetic operator `2+3 == 5`. The complexity is `O(n + m)`, where `n` is number of elements in `A`, `m` -- number of elements in `B`. If the sets are ordered (tree-based implementation instead of hash-based one) then the complexity is `O(n*log(n) + m*log(m))` i.e., it is worse.